Guidelines on designing a TCP protocol for continuous stream of data
I have a continuous data stream over a TCP socket. I am in control over both server and client to implement a protocol. The basic requirement is that I can synchronize onto the stream of data. Ideally, I'd like to send packets, but TCP is stream-oriented and there is no concept of packets. So I want the application layer to handle the packaging of the byte-stream.
I have found two common strategies to do this:

Use a delimiter to start/end a message. This has the drawback that I need to encode the (binary) data so that it doesn't contain the delimiter.
Use fixed length messages and figure out a way to "lock" to the stream. This strategy I find difficult to comprehend. Modbus TCP allegedly works like this, and uses a transaction identifier and more information so that the receiving end can figure out where the message ends. But how does it know for sure where the message starts?

This blog post gives implementation details, but I think it relies on receiving packets "by accident" that it should not be able to rely on. Even Modbus TCP implementations seem to rely on calling the OS socket function recv with a length parameter to receive "complete messages" or something like that, even though they should not, according to other sources that I trust.
Can someone shine a light on this?
PS: This whole system runs on a LAN that is fully under our control.
Background
Our initial development went like this:

(Embedded) server sends (what I thought to be) a "packet" over TCP
On the PC side, the Python function socket.recv would receive the complete "packet"

We then needed to implement the "packet" reception in C++ (using Boost ASIO) and I found out that the packet concept doesn't exist in TCP.


This blog post gives implementation details, but I think it relies on receiving packets "by accident" that it should not be able to rely on

I take it you have read the closing "Warning" on the linked blog:

But, since we are working with a network buffer, the first recv might not get all 4 characters in one recv. If you choose to ignore this, in high network loads your code will break. To be bulletproof, you need two recv loops, to first determine the length, and the second part to get the data.

That's your answer.¹
In ASIO this amounts to not using [async_]read_some but instead us the composed read operations

asio::[async_]read
asio::[async_]read_until
asio::[async_]read

If your buffer is dynamic/overdimensioned, keep in mind that all of them can read beyond the minimum required to satisfy the match condition e.g.:

This function is used to asynchronously read data into the specified dynamic buffer sequence until the dynamic buffer sequence's get area contains the specified delimiter.

To deal with the situation when one composed read resulted in a buffer containing multiple complete messages, the composed

This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the stream's async_read_some function, and is known as a composed operation. If the dynamic buffer sequence's get area already contains the delimiter, this asynchronous operation completes immediately.

If you need concrete programming advice, I suggest posting a question with  relevant code. Meanwhile, I have a LOT of examples on this site showing how to elegantly deal with composed reads in different message framing scenarios (a start).
An example that shows how pre-bufferred data will still correctly be processed using the composed operations: unget or similar solution for boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream

¹ I won't go into ModBus, but I will note it isn't a TCP protocol per se. In fact, it usually isn't. When it is, it's most likely on the loopback network (or another virtual host-only type network) which probably has different characteristics which make that implementation OK. Otherwise they may just have different QoS goals (e.g. it's okay to miss a few messages)?

Thank you for your answer; it does answer my question. The point of QoS goals is, at least for me, the core of it.
